# Eclipse: Edit target editor template?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, editor, target

I've come into a project that requires loading a lot of target definitions. A lot of it is a blackbox, so I have little influence, but I can edit files in my eclipse installation folder, so yay for that.

The target files are loaded/build via Tycho/Maven.

I have a problem with the target editor's template (see screenshot below) - I find the position of the "Reload"-button highly inconvenient, as the length of the plugin names approximates eternity due to internal naming conventions. I need to scroll the eclipse window whenever I want to set the target platform or reload a definition.

Where can I edit the template that defines how the target editor looks, so I can limit the overall width or reposition the elements?

[image: Eternal scroll bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target editor `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.targetdefinition.TargetEditor` is a `FormEditor` with hard coded layout. There is no template that can be changed to alter its layout.

Comment: Meh.Is there any way to hack it?

Comment: No, there is no way to change it short of modifying the source code.